# How to modify Query Options no_format to allow some format, but not others?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

I have to replicate a Google Sheet, and am using  ImportRange and Query together. I need Query also because the first sheet has urls under them, which I cannot have on the copied sheet. I was able to remove the urls by using Query Options no_format.  Options no_value also does the same job. However, neither of them allow any format change to transfer, at least not that I have found. I want to have the **bold** format to transfer, font size to transfer, and new rows  added in the middle of the sheet to transfer, but not color. Is there ability to do this in Query Options no_format or Options no_values? Or is there some other way I can make this happen?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please describe the _problem_ rather than describing your _attempted solution_.  See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676) Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Answer (score -1):

The `importrange()` function does not copy *formats* — no spreadsheet formula can do that, as they only deal with *values*. You will need a script to copy range formats such as font weight and font size.

The `format` clause works fine in a `query()` formula, but it does not let you transfer cell formatting such as font size, bolding or color. It only lets you specify number formatting for integers, floats, dates, times, datetimes and booleans.

See [Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Format).

Comment: Thank-you for your answer doubleunary. It seems I need to use a script. Does anyone know how to write a script that I could use to have all formats copy over with ImportRange except for color and underlying urls?

Comment: That's [off-topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741) in this question. Please post a new question.